# Как правильно передать русским языком последнюю букву "guest house"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Гестхаус (гест хаус) или гестхауз (гест хауз)?
(Слово давно вошло в наш язык, но имеет два варианта написания. Обоснуйте, какой из них правильный.)

В моих статьях (публиковался в трёх разных газетах) часто употреблялось это слово. Причём все три редактора (авторский текст проходит через редактора в обязательном порядке) оставили одинаковый вариант написания: гэст-хауз, в гэст-хаузе, гэст-хаузы. Редактора между собой не были знакомы. Получается, все сделали одинаковую ошибку? (Могу дать ссылки).

Вот 2 дополнительных источника в пользу "з": 
[https://complex_words.academic.ru/629/гестхауз](https://complex_words.academic.ru/629/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7)
https://meganorm.ru/Data2/1/4293824/4293824728.pdf

Answer (score 1):

В единственном числе в английском слове "house" чётко звучит звук С. Другое дело, что во множественном /хаузиз/.

Comment: У меня слух совсем не летучей мыши, но в школе учили, что s в интервокальной позиции озвончается. Ради этого "немое е" и пишется.

Comment: Можно посмотреть словарную транскрипцию и английское/американское произношение. Уверенное С, в отличие от rose (rəuz).

Comment: @Alex_ander а где вы посмотрите авторитетную транскрипцию?! Произношение мне мало что даст. Я там слышу Z - как в школе и учили. Знаете, этот парадокс известен психологом. Мы **слышим** то, что **хотим** услышать.

Comment: @behemothus: транскрипция ведь это то же произношение, только зафиксированное словарём. Разве [тут](https://forvo.com/word/house/#en) вы можете допустить З в каком-то из произношений?

Comment: **Допустить** могу во всех. А судить не берусь, не слышу.))

Comment: (+) Вы неверно вопрос ставите. Чтобы понять, что слышит человек надо сравнить с возможными вариантами. Так вот, я слышу звук, который отличается и от his, и от ass. Ничто не мешает мне считать его звонким.

Comment: @behemothus Первоначально я посмотрел в софтовом  Lingvo (по умолчанию был открыт LingvoUniversal - видимо, сводный словарь русских составителей). Поключил другие словари и нашел такие вариации.  В словаре OxfordAmerican приводится "окающее" произношение, но тоже с "С": [hous] (сам слышал такое в Канаде. но списал на их региональное). Согласно словарю CollinsCobuild - [ha͟ʊs], хотя специально отмечено, что _глагол_ произносится как [ha͟ʊz] - этого я не знал, но это единственный найденный случай озвончения в конце слова (там есть еще несколько словарей).

Comment: @behemothus Есть гораздо более известный случай с конечными -se, где произношение определяется тем, существительное это [s] или глагол [z]: слово **use**.

Comment: @Alex_ander: точно, или прилагательное/глагол *close.*

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, недопустимо *раздельное* написание: если словосочетание заимствуется как нарицательное (а не как совокупность траслитераций в кавычках), то его составляющие должны получить трактовку как части речи. В языке оригинала первая часть сочетания - *прилагательное* (гостевой; возможна трактовка и в притяжательном смысле), но при буквальном заимствовании оно не имеет русских грамматических признаков прилагательного и не может склоняться. Приемлемы два варианта: *слитное* написание **гестхаус** и *через дефис*, **гест-хаус** (ср. *компакт-диск, арт-хаус*). Слитное написание хорошо в случае, когда носитель языка *не* выделяет для себя смысловых частей (хаус, диск - в русском устоялось восприятие таких фрагментов по смыслу), поэтому *дефисный* вариант предпочтителен и имеет шансы со временем закрепиться.

Comment: Автор спрашивает про последнюю букву (с/з), а слитно-раздельно - это, так сказать, бонус.

Answer (score 0):

Пока написание не закреплено словарями говорить о правильном написании вообще - невозможно. Кстати, утверждение, что "слово вошло в русский язык", тоже подтверждается словарями - и только так.

Вообще есть два основных подхода к передаче на письме иностранных слов: транскрипция и транслитерация. Первая, по-простому говоря, передает звуки слова, вторая передает слово побуквенно (на практике - кроме случаев дифтонгов и диграфов). Чаще всего по факту используется некая смешанная система, отдельная для каждой пары языков, закрепленная в так называемых "таблицах практической транскрипции". Беда в том, что подобные таблицы разработаны для передачи в первую очередь имен собственных, причем даже в этом случае всегда фиксируются многочисленные отступления.
Для имен нарицательных написание не попавших пока в словарь слов, увы, никак не регламентировано.
Так что тут есть только субъективное мнение, о оно мне подсказывает,  что это английское звонкое конечное S чаще передается русским С (доктор Хаус хотя бы).

Так что я за вариант **гестхаус**. Про слитное написание - см. Alex_ander.

Comment: Не могу понять вашей фразы в конце первого абзаца. Мне она кажется незаконченной.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да, спасибо. Взбрыкнул комп при редактировании, пропала строка. Исправил.